# How to rename Spring MVC Web App context root?

Tags: java, spring, spring-web, contextpath

I'm trying to rename my Spring MVC web application.
When I run it, there is an old name in the URL:
http://localhost:8080/oldName/

In project Properties>Resource I set Path: /newName
and also in Web Project Settings, Context root: newName

But it didn't work, I still have http://localhost:8080/oldName/
How to rename it?

Comment: Check how to change context-path of the project and you can do it from POM.xml.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one ways and it depends on if you are using spring-boot for example or not:

1. In application.properties/yml file:

> server.servlet.context-path=/newName

2. Java System Property:

You can also set the context path as a Java system property before even the context is initialized:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/newName");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

3. OS Environment Variable:

Linux:

> export SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/newName

Windows:

> set SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/newName

The above environment variable is for Spring Boot 2.x.x,  If we have 1.x.x, the variable is SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH.

4. Command Line Arguments

We can set the properties dynamically via command line arguments as well:

> java -jar app.jar --server.servlet.context-path=/newName

5. Using Java Config

With Spring Boot 2, we can use WebServerFactoryCustomizer:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/newName");
}
```

With Spring Boot 1, we can create an instance of EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer embeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
    return container -> container.setContextPath("/newName");
}
```

6. Eclipse + Maven

   `<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.9</version>
       <configuration>
           <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
           <wtpContextName>newName</wtpContextName>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>`

   7. Eclipse + Gradle

   `apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'war'
   apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
   eclipse {
       wtp {
           component {
               contextPath = 'newName'
           }
       }
   }`

Following links might be helpful:

- [Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path)
- [Mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-change-web-project-context-root/)

Answer (score 0):

For my case , I use ECLIPSE for developping my project.

In order to get the desired url after clicking "Run on Server" , I also need to amend the following line of server.xml under Tomcat-v9.0 as below :

```
<Context docBase="newName" path="/newName" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:newName"/></Host>
```

P.S.
I have checked below :
In project Properties>Resource I set Path: /newName and also in Web Project Settings, Context root: newName